# WPF: Opacity and the MouseEnter Event

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, opacity

As part of a diagram, I am drawing a few overlapping Shapes, each with `Opacity=0.5`, like here:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Opacity="0.5" MouseEnter="Rectangle_MouseEnter" />
    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Opacity="0.5" />
</Grid>


private void Rectangle_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
  {
     MessageBox.Show("Entered");
  }
```

When the user enters the shape with the mouse, some additional information should be displayed, but the event handler never gets called.

Is there a way to get MouseEnter events for all Shapes, instead of just the topmost one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your layout only the topmost rectangle will raise MouseEnter event. It fully overlaps the first rectangle.

Try this code for eventHandler:

```
private void Rectangle_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != grid.Children[0])
            {
                var rect = (grid.Children[0] as Rectangle);
                if (rect != null) rect.RaiseEvent(e);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Entered.");
            }
        }
```

For this works you need to subscribe both rectangles to Rectangle_MouseEnter.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. =) Is there another way to get notified when the user enters a region that is behind something else?

Comment: I'm afraid that no... MouseEnter and MouseLeave events don't bubble and raise only over exactly that control on which you place your cursor. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189029(v=VS.95).aspx#mouse_routed_events